# Fragments, Parcelable Objects, and the Back Stack

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

Let's assume I have Fragment 1 and Fragment 2.

Fragment 1 creates a `Person` object and sets the `name` property to "George".

Fragment 1 then creates Fragment 2, passes the Person object as a `Parcelable`, then pushes Fragment 2 onto the back stack.

Fragment 2 reads in the parcelable.  Later, Fragment 2 changes the `name` of the `Person` to Nancy.

The user hits the back button, popping Fragment 2 off the stack and returning to Fragment 1.

What is the `Person` object's `name` property now that we are back in Fragment 1?  Is it set to George or Nancy?

Comment: that sounds like it would be rather easy to check..

Comment: It is.  But my results from checking are unexpected.  I would have expected it to still be George in Fragment 1.  However, in my app, it is Nancy.  I'm trying to discover if I'm misinterpreting the behavior of the back button/back stack OR if my code is doing something wonky that is allowing this to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that in `Fragment2` what you get is actually a reference to the parcelable object from `Fragment1`. This way, you can make the conclusion that you're modifying the same object.

[Android docs:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html)

> An unusual feature of Parcel is the ability to read and write active objects. For these objects the actual contents of the object is not written, rather a special token referencing the object is written. When reading the object back from the Parcel, you do not get a new instance of the object, but rather a handle that operates on the exact same object that was originally written.

If it helps you know what to do ;)

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, good answer!  I do have one more question though... what would an Android user EXPECT based on their usage of the "Back" button?  Would a user expect `Person` to be modified?

Comment: It depends on the data flow of your application. For example, take an android contact from contacts app and modify it. When you press **Back** you'll see your contact updated, right?

Comment: I never noticed that about the Contacts app... it's interesting because it has a "Save" button and a "Cancel" button, but if you simply hit the Android back button, it decides to save.